# Is there a punishment for voting on your own question?

Tags: support

Is there a punishment/against-the-rules for voting on your own question to help others see it and/or help it gain popularity?

Comment: No, there's no sort of punishment. You are simply prevented from voting on your own questions or answers. Yeah, I tried.

Comment: Ok! thank you... :)

Comment: If you're interested in making your question more visible, when you get over 75 reputation, you may add a bounty. This puts it in the featured questions list.